# CUDA/TensorFlow compatibility

Tags: tensorflow

Is the latest version of TensorFlow (2.1.0) compatible with the latest version of CUDA (10.2) ?
And also with latest version of cuDNN (7.6) ?
Thanks.

Comment: There seem to be unresolved issues as well as [promising recommendations](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler). (cuDNN 7.6 [looks official](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).)

Answer (score 1):

The following image provide is an the officially tested combination of CUDA and TensorFlow 2.1.0

[image]

For more details please refer overview of tested combination for [windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) and [Linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).